# Why always show error while I create my file through angular-cli or angular-seed?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

This shows I can't find a module. How can I remove this problem? Please reply how can I fix my problem.

Here is my `main.ts` code:

```typescript
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

And a screenshot, showing the file tree:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: when i download angular-seed from angular.io then it also show many error as please include npm-debug-log file in your folder?

Comment: Images can't be searched or copied, and offer poor accessibility. Please always post text as text. You can select code blocks and click the `{}` button or press Ctrl+K to indent it by four spaces, which tells Stack Overflow to treat it as code. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for details. I have done this for you on this post. Good luck!

Comment: So, it shows an error. Which error? When doing what?